# using trim with arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, trim

I have following array

```
Array ( [0] => ï»¿ [1] => Commodities [2] => Crude Oil [3] => 91.46 [4] => + 0.48% [5] => Natural Gas [6] => 4.54 [7] => + 0.38% [8] => Gasoline [9] => 2.49 [10] => + 0.49% [11] => Heating Oil [12] => 2.65 [13] => + 0.84% [14] => Gold [15] => 1368.07 [16] => + 0.40% [17] => Silver [18] => 28.78 [19] => + 1.62% [20] => Copper [21] => 4.41 [22] => + 0.14% [23] => Quotes delayed 15 min. [24] => » Add to your site )
```

i want an array like

```
Array([0]=>Array
(name => Crude oil
price => 91.46
precent => +0.48)
[1]=>Array
(name => Natural Gas
...
..
and so on upto Copper
)
```

i tried using

```
for ($i = 2; $i <6 ; $i = $i +3) {
   $commoditiesdatagot[] = array (
   trim($arraymain[$i]),
   trim($arraymain[$i +1]),
   trim($arraymain[$i +2])
   );
  }
```

but i keep getting following error -

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset:  25 in /var/www/html/iphorex/live/commodities.php on line 51

Notice: Undefined offset:  25 in /var/www/html/iphorex/live/commodities.php on line 51
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset:  26 in /var/www/html/iphorex/live/commodities.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined offset:  26 in /var/www/html/iphorex/live/commodities.php on line 49
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset:  27 in /var/www/html/iphorex/live/commodities.php on line 50
```

where line 51 is `trim($arraymain[$i +2])`.

Any help ..........

Comment: you don't want trimming your expected result is differently structured array

Comment: can you please provide the input array with `var_export`. I am not in the mood to convert it back to a parseable representation.

Comment: Are you showing the right code? Your loop is constrained with `$i<6`. How can `$i+2` be 25.

Comment: `25/3` return fraction, is this what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with trim(). In your for() cycle, you are sending your $i variable to 25, 26, 27 ([$i], [$i+1], [$i+2]) while your $arraymain has 24 elements in it.

```
$arraymain = array_slice($arraymain,2,-2);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arraymain); $i += 3) {
   $commoditiesdatagot[] = array (
   trim($arraymain[$i]),
   trim($arraymain[$i+1]),
   trim($arraymain[$i+2])
   );
  }
```

print_r($arraymain);

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to do this with a callback function:

```
// Define callback function, note &$item is passed by reference
function trim_r(&$item, $key)
{
    // If the item is an array, recursively use array_walk 
    if(is_array($item))
        array_walk($item, 'trim_r');
    // Trim the item
    else if(is_string($item))
        $item = trim($item);
}

// This is an example array
$yourArray = array(" Jake ", " John ", array( " Helen "));

// Show the array without being trimmed
var_dump($yourArray);

// Trim the array
array_walk($yourArray, 'trim_r');

// Display the trimmed array
var_dump($yourArray);
```

Comment: you may use [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Answer (score 1):

you have to check if your loop uses the correct interval. the error message tells you, that you try to access a variable in your array on position: 25 and 26, but your array only has 25 items indexed by 0 to 24. so array[25] is not available.

your loop could also look like this i guess:

```
$i = 2;
while($i < count($arraymain)){
   $row = array();
   if(isset($arraymain[$i+2]){
      $row[] = $arraymain[$i]; $i++;
      $row[] = $arraymain[$i]; $i++;
      $row[] = $arraymain[$i]; $i++;

      $commoditiesdatagot[] = $row;
    } else error_log("index out of bounce ".$i+2);
}
```

Comment: the end ouf your array is now extra row but some other information ... so you can also try to check `$i < count($arraymain) - 2` in your while.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an all-in-one:

```
array_map(                                      // apply
    function($chunk) {                          // this callback that
        return array_combine(                   // makes a new array
            array('name', 'price', 'percent'),  // with these keys
            array_map('trim', $chunk)           // and those trimmed values
        );
    },                                          
    array_chunk(                                // from the chunks of
        array_slice($data, 2, -2),              // this $data array subset
        3                                       // having three chunks each
     )
 );
```

Note that this requires the input data to have 3 elements each per Commodity. Your input array is missing a price for Gasoline, so any solutions presented so far will choke on that when creating the commodity subsets.

You could also move the trimming into the lower part before you are chunking the array. This would invoke the call just once instead of multiple times on the individual chunks. Not sure if it makes a huge difference though.

[See live demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gzR2hW)